# Character selection in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to store the user's choice when he presses one of these buttons, and after that, the player will choose an enemy character, these characters are in a collection type. Here is what I have done so far, I am thinking userdefaultsection to store value, but how I do it at the button presses.

//MARK:- Player choose

```
@objc func tupacButtonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
    if let playerChoosed = characters[1] {
        print(playerChoosed)
    }

}

@objc func biggieButtonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
    if let playerChoosed = characters[2] {
        print(playerChoosed)
    }
}

@objc func akonButtonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
    if let playerChoosed = characters[3] {
        print(playerChoosed)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `characters`? And consider that indices of collection types start at zero.

Comment: is the variable that holds a dictionary of characters.let characters = [1: "2Pac", 2: "BIG", 3:"Akon"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 action and connect it to all the buttons  with

```
var choosen = "" 
@objc func allBtns(_ sender: UIButton!) 
  choosen = characters[sender.tag]
}
```

Assign a tag to the buttons from 0 to 2 respectively